# How to find out what version of Pages/Numbers/Key was the file created in?

Tags: ios, metadata, iwork, fileversioninfo

My issue is that I am not sure how to find out what was the version of apple software that a file was created in. I am not a heavy user of apple products, but I need to be able to figure out what version were files created in.

I see in index.xml the following code

```
<sl:document xmlns:sfa="http://developer.apple.com/namespaces/sfa" xmlns:sf="http://developer.apple.com/namespaces/sf" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:sl="http://developer.apple.com/namespaces/sl" sl:version="72007061400" sfa:ID="SLPublicationModel-0" sl:generator="slingshot" sl:app_build_date="Jan 22 2008, 01:09:42">
```

Within the sl:document tag there's the sl:version="72007061400", vs all the version-history. Where can I find out what this version corresponds to?

If there is some resource for apple formats I can look to check against versions that would be awesome. If I am not looking in the right spot please correct me.

Comment: I seriously doubt that Apple publishes how it creates this value - however you may be able to reverse engineer it by looking at various versions of the programs, and looking at the Version specified in the "About" box. You could also ask this question on the internal Apple forums - its more likely to be seen by an Apple Engineer.

Comment: Currently I don't have access to iOS machine, and when I do about on windows, I don't see the version number there, i'll try posting that on apple forums

Comment: nevermind on that - It looks like I need to pay to be able to post on those forums unless I missed something.

Comment: You are not a registered Apple developer? I think all you need to do is register for a "free" account, but not sure its been a while...

Comment: I can view, but not post as a free account